# displaying a view immediately after the 'store' resource controller in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, url, homestead

so at the moment my 'store' resource controller adds to the table in my database and fetches the view for my 'index' page (my home page) however when i refresh this view it duplicates the last row added to the database. i have noticed the URI is 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/store' instead of 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/index' can someone please explain what is going on. i apologise for the lack of technical terms i'm a new apprentice and am trying to figure this out using my own initiative but so far have had no luck. i also noticed that my log out function does the same thing although the URI is slightly different in that it still displays the CSRF token in the URI however it still says its at the 'logout' file path, here is an example of this; 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout?_token=bqTl4J3EZyKj7LS5ZvqfRB8k1Qg02IT1j4WlBG51&dir2login='

FYI i have already tried return $this->index();

my logout controller method;

```
  public function logout(){
  Auth::logout();
  return view('index',['posts'=>$this->getTable()]);
}
```

---

my store controller method:

```
public function store(Request $request){
  //creates new row in database table
  //$clientIp=$request->ip();
  $post = new PostModel();
  //gets email of user currently logged in
  $post->email=Auth::user()->email;
  $post->ip=$request->ip();
  $post->content=$request->content;
  $post->company=$request->company;
  $post->rating=$request->rating;
  //saves to database
  $post->save();
  return view('index',['posts'=>$this->getTable()]);
}
```

Comment: Do you also have an `index()` in the controller?

Comment: Can you supply your `index()` and your Routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

> return redirect('/');

Comment: hi yes i did try this, however i used index instead of /

/ worked ! 



thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here is get the user to the index view. However, instead of returning a different view (and having to define the logic of 'posts' again), it's much easier to redirect the user to the index method of your controller. You have multiple options to do so. I have three listed below:

This is what you currently have:

```
return view('index',['posts'=>$this->getTable()]);\
```

you could do with the "**action**" (ControllerName@FunctionName):

```
return redirect()->action('PostController@index');
```

or with a "**named route**":

```
return redirect()->route('posts.index');
```

or to a direct URL

```
return redirect('/');
```